# Error Data source name not found and no default driver specified with Odbc in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm having this error when i try to add some data from UI into MSSQL database and through all the questions&answers about this error i found, couldn't understand where the problem is. Could anyone give me some help? Thanks.

```
OdbcConnection conexiune = new OdbcConnection("Data Source=CODRINMA\\codrinma;Initial Catalog=BD;Integrated Security=True");
conexiune.Open();
OdbcCommand cominsert = new OdbcCommand("insert into Tabela(idX,denumire,adresa,idY) values(?,?,?,?)", conexiune);
cominsert.Parameters.Clear();
cominsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idX", int.Parse(txtID.Text.Trim()));
cominsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@denumire", char.ToUpper(txtDenumire.Text.Trim()[0]) + txtDenumire.Text.Trim().Substring(1));
cominsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adresa", char.ToUpper(txtAdresa.Text.Trim()[0]) + txtAdresa.Text.Trim().Substring(1));
cominsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idY", int.Parse(cmbCamp.SelectedValue.ToString()));
cominsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Message!!");
conexiune.Close();
this.Dispose();
```

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Answer (score 0):

When using ODBC you need to include the driver to use in the connection string.

See [`OdbcConnection.ConnectionString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.connectionstring.aspx).

For instance if your server is SQL Server then add

```
driver={SQL Server}
```

to the connection string.